# Accepting empty inputs with scanf() in C

Tags: c, input, scanf

I want to read two digit entered by the user. But the thing is that user may enter just 1 number too. So the list of inputs could be like this:

```
1  2
2
4  2
15
```

It is a simple question but I could not find the exact problem asked. Most of the problems ask for an empty string input but it is a case of integers now.

Thanks

Comment: Read a string and then parse it to see how many values the user entered

Comment: @UnholySheep I see, nice solution. But does the structure of scanf() not allow a direct way? Thanks

Comment: `scanf` is intended for *precisely* formatted input, it is not intended to deal with arbitrary user input - so no, there is no direct safe way of handling this using `scanf` formatting specifiers

Comment: So have your user typed two numbers three times, or one number six times? Or maybe two, one, two, one? How are we supposed to know?

Comment: @n.m. maximum 2 numbers in each input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` is for formatted input output. This doesn't go with you requirement. Just as being mentioned use `fgets` to read the whole line and then parse the number inputted by using something like `strtol` etc.

```
#define MAXLEN 60
....
char pp[MAXLEN+1];
if(fgets(pp,MAXLEN+1,stdin) == NULL ){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in input");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char *ptr = pp;
char *end;
errno = 0;
long i = strtol(ptr, &end, 10);
while( ptr != end )
{
    ptr = end;
    if (errno == ERANGE){
        printf("range error, got ");
        errno = 0;
    }
    printf("Got - %ld\n", i);
    /* work with i */
    i = strtol(ptr, &end, 10);
}
```

Demo of the code [here](https://ideone.com/5QkBnt).